# how does meteor handle async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, callback

Starting working on a new meteor app, I have already done some node.js projects with callbacks or promises to handle async code but going through meteor tutorials; some async methods have no callbacks or promises. how is this handled?
example code from a tutorial:

```
var party = Parties.findOne(partyId);
if (!party)
  throw new Meteor.Error(404, "No such party");
if (party.owner !== this.userId)
  throw new Meteor.Error(404, "No such party");
if (party.public)
  throw new Meteor.Error(400,
    "That party is public. No need to invite people.");
```

how can he fetch from db and perform operations on party

Answer (score 2):

Meteor uses magical abstraction for coroutines called Fiber. It works same as async/await in many other languages. 
To desribe it as simply as possible:
There actually are callbacks underneath, but You just don't need to handle them by hand.

https://github.com/laverdet/node-Fibers

/Edit
There is a great article on MeteorHacks describing how Fibers work:
https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor